# Scroll bar missing from web app and unable to scroll

Tags: html, css, angular

The vertical scroll bar in my angular app does not appear when items on the page go beyond the view. The scroll bar was there and I don't recall changing anything before it went missing. I have been stuck on this for days. I have checked the first 6 pages of similar questions asked on SO and after implementing all suggestions, nothing has made the scroll bar re-appear. I have also googled for the answer but again, none of the suggestions have made it re-appear. Things I have tried:

- Individually commenting out all CSS style sheets one by one to see if one of them was causing the issue
- Individually commenting out all HTML files one by one to see if one of them was causing the issue
- Adding 'overflow: auto' to the global styles, to every other style sheet in my app using the * CSS selector and to the item-list-container (see below)
- Adding 'overflow-y: scroll' to the same places as detailed above (this forces a scroll bar to appear but the page still doesn't scroll)
- Made sure there are no 'overflow: hidden' styles on any of the style sheets

Here is an image of the app (the scroll bar should be on the right hand side):

[image]

Here is the main global style.css file:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
  }

  /* Track */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }

  /* Handle */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: black;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
```

Here is the style sheet from the component that is displayed in the above image:

```
ul {
    margin:0 10px 0 0;
    padding:0;   
}

li { list-style: none; }

.item-list-container {
    column-count: 4;
    column-gap: 1.1em;
    margin-top: 107px;   
}

.like-icon {
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 420px;
}
```

Here is the html from the component in the above image:

```
<ul class="container">
    <li class="item-list-container oneSec">
        <app-image-item
          *ngFor="let imageEl of galleryList"
          [image]="imageEl"
          (click)="onImageSelect(imageEl)">
          <div *ngIf="isLoggedIn" class="like-container">
            <ion-icon class="like-icon" name="heart"></ion-icon>
        </div> 
        </app-image-item>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions before I throw my computer out of the window?

Comment: can you give me stackblitz?

Answer (score 2):

Go in style css.

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

or use overflow property with your container.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Adding the suggested code above to the global style.css file did not resolve the issue (the scroll bar does not re-appear and I am unable to scroll still). Do you mean add 'overflow: auto' to the item-list-container? I have already done this (see original post above)

Comment: can you give me a stackblitz?

Comment: I haven't used stackblitz before, I will have a look now